# How can I avoid a circular import in this case (Flask and SQLalchemy)?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, circular-dependency

I have a FLASK application that uses SQLalchemy for the database.

The models are all in *models.py*, and I have added several properties and methods to the default ORM properties and methods of most model classes.
For example; my "contract" model has an extra property contract.first_possible_termination that returns a date.

The problem is that this property accesses a *utilities* module that has a function to calculate a range of dates. And that function needs to use different configuration options that are stored in the database, in a "configuration" table.

So the utilities module needs to use the ORM models again, to access the Configuration table and thus we have a circular import:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Configuration
```

I'm wondering what the standard way is to avoid a circular import here. I imagine more people run into this as one adds methods and properties to ones models.

**EDIT, PLEASE NOTE:**
I think plantians answer is the best way to go in general, because it promotes SoC, but in my specific case I'm working with a legacy database that has values that influence business rules spread across the different tables in the database.
A lot of the functionality I'm adding to my models will depend in some way or another on these values/business rules, so I will not be able to avoid accessing the database in these functions without refactoring considerably and passing a lot of extra external values to my helper functions.

I can only accept one answer, but both are valid, so an upvote for both, but Blubber's answer is my personal solution for now.
Thanks to both Blubber and Plantian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import the module inside the function instead of on the top of your module, modules get only imported once, so this shouldn't pose a performance problem.

You can also try to move the configuration module import to the bottom of your util module.

Comment: Hi Blubber, 
This works, but isn't it un-Pythonic to move an import inside a method instead of at the top of the page? Is this standard practice for Python circular imports?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to pass the configuration into the utility function as an argument.  Probably best to not have your utilities depend on the model directly. Ie.

```
def get_range (start_at, strategy):
    pass
```

Where strategy is detemined by the caller (from the config table).  Maybe a code snippet of your util function would be easier to build off of.

Comment: Thanks Plantian, this has crossed my mind, but this is a membership system where lots of small helper functions depend on values in the database. For example, the startdate of a membership might be on the date when the member starts, or at the beginning of the next debit period, which is configurable in the membership. There are dozens of these business rules stored in the database...